# Windows 10: differentiate between preinstalled app and downloaded app

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

One of my clients has a deal with an OEM. Their app X will be preinstalled on a number of laptops. This app will receive updates from the Windows 10 store. This app X will also available for download in the Windows 10 store to other users. Only users using the preinstalled version should receive a free 3-month trial.

Unfortunately, the OEM is not providing any device IDs, and the users are not getting any unlock codes for their trial. I came up with the following initial "solution":

- Use version 1.0.1.0 for the preinstalled app.
- Upload 1.0.0.0 to the store.

When the app starts and the version is 1.0.1.0, it is identified as a preinstalled version, at which point I can make a server call to send a device ID to the client's server to recognize this device even after app deletions.

I can update the store app without losing any knowledge of preinstalled apps since I can update to any version below 1.0.1.0. This means the preinstalled version will not be overwritten by auto update with the store version (since the installed version number is greater than the store version). However, if a serious bug is detected in the preinstalled version, I cannot update that app or a certain class of users will not receive their free trial. Namely, the users that have not started the app on the device yet before Windows 10 updates the app with the new version (1.0.1.1 for example).

This all sounds unnecessarily complicated, and I hope it is. Can anyone think of an easier way to distinguish between the preinstalled and downloaded version that's foolproof?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you include a bool trigger in the app resources or a hashed string that determines if it is trial/full/oem?

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't work when the app gets updated by the windows store before the user launches the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already thinking about offering 2 different versions, this one might be a better solution, where you can deploy two times the version `1.0.0.0`.

Instead of using the versions to differ between the state, use build symbols.
Create two differnt builds, one for your OEM client, and one for store deployment.

For the OEM, where you want to allow the trial, use the following - as an example:

```
private bool CanUseTrial()
{
#if OEM
    return true;
#else
    return false;
#endif
}
```

Doing it this way will allow you to maintain the same code base for all clients, but differing between case OEM and case store deployment, without much logic needed.

**EDIT #1:**

To address the problem of OEM clients updating to non-OEM clients, you can still go with this approach (as long as the app runs at least once as #OEM build):

```
private async Task<bool> CanUseTrial()
{
    var clientCode = GenerateClientCode(); // However you're going to do this

#if OEM        
    WebServiceXyz.RegisterOemClient(clientCode);
    return true;
#else
    try
    {
        return await WebServiceXyz.IsRegisteredOemClient(clientCode);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Hi Herdo, thank you for your reaction! The problem lies in the Windows 10 auto update. Specifically, if I detect a bug in the preinstalled version and I update to a new version, it might happen that the preinstalled app gets replaced by the store version before the user starts the app. This means I can no longer detect this install as a preinstall.

Comment: This is why I thought a higher version number might be better, since that at least allows me to update the store version without losing information about the trial users.

Comment: But the app will run at least once as #OEM build, before updating to a newer version, even if a newer version is available?

Comment: @JorisWeimar I made an edit for you, please read the comment above, too.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. If I am assured the app runs at least once, there is no problem because then I can differentiate the apps (at least once, and therefore indefinitely since in that one run I write to localsettings and/or make a call to the server to register the device with some device identifier) (like you suggest in your edit)

Comment: @JorisWeimar Do you know if the OEM sets up the user accounts for the final users?

Comment: No, we don't have this information unfortunately. What I was hoping for was the availability of some sort of API that allows me to determine the first installed version an app, or something along those lines.

Comment: @JorisWeimar Microsoft currently doesn't offer any API, concerning the App Store apps, that would let you inspect the "historical data" of a client.

Comment: I mark your answer as correct, since there probably isn't any way to do it. Thanks!